# Difference Result of Numerical Satellite Propagator

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, simulation, gmat

Currently, I am trying to build a numerical propagator platform for satellite that accommodates for all kinds of perturbation. So, for validation purpose, I compare the result of my own program and GMAT as the reference. For simplicity, I only introduce harmonic perturbation to the propagator. However, the result in terms of semi-major axis differs along the time. At the end of 10 days simulation, it differs up to 300m as shown follows.
[image]

I already create same input for my program and GMAT: delta time, integration method, keplerian orbit parameter, degree and order of earth oblateness and aspherical, and frame reference. Then, I also look at the difference between my program and GMAT perturbation due to the harmonic one. The differences increase from 1E-15 up to 1E-7. Is it possible the root cause due to python numpy.float64 datatype that only accommodates 8bytes? Any suggestion is really helpful.
[image]

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* My first suggestion would be to give much more detailed information about your implementation of the numerical integration. For example, did you use one of the routines available from [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)? If so, please include at least part (if not all) of your script, especially the line calling solve_ivp so we can see what you've specified. If you're not using that and perhaps have scripted a numerical integrator yourself, please give details about that instead.

Comment: Also, what is the approximate time step that you integrator is using? At a semimajor axis of 42,000 km the perturbation effects of the Sun and Moon will be huge; are you absolutely sure those are turned off in your GMAT simulation?

Comment: Thank you @uhoh for the response. I create my own integration module, i.e. rk4 and abm8. So, I assume there is no problem there with your concern. I use 60seconds for timestep both in my program and GMAT, turning off lunisolar effect, relativity effect, and drag effect both in my program and GMAT. My current concern is I want to validate my program by using established platform. For another insight, I try to use 6seconds timestep and I get better results that close to the GMAT. That's why I suspect python precision float as the culprit.

Comment: Oh that's great! You might like to upgrade to RK45 ([Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method)), which allows for automatic variable step size. [start's at the bottom of page 3 of the PDF](https://math.okstate.edu/people/yqwang/teaching/math4513_fall11/Notes/rungekutta.pdf) I wrote this script a million years ago when I was [starting to learn Python in Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=RK45). Written fo readability, not speed: https://pastebin.com/HgByHcLw

Comment: You are right to worry about numerical round-off errors, which is one reason folks use integrators of much higher order than 4 rather than to to tinier and tinier step sizes, cf. [DOP853](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#:~:text=%E2%80%98-,DOP853,-%E2%80%99%3A%20Explicit%20Runge%2DKutta) (you can see RK45 there as well)

Comment: Python's "float" is 64-bit (equivalent to a double in C).  I would suspect GMAT is the same, as that's the largest size common modern processors support.  So, going to higher precision either requires specialized hardware, or very slow software emulation.

Comment: @GregMiller yes indeed, so my recommendation for a higher order integrator can mean substantially fewer iterations (and total flop) and so lower roundoff error *by the end of the integration*, without resorting to higher precision.

Comment: It's very important to remember that in IEEE 754 several of the properties of the reals fail. For example, associativity dictates that $(a+b)+c$ must equal $a+(b+c)$. This is not always the case using the IEEE 754 floating point standard, which is what almost all computers now use. You rolled your own integrator. It's not at all surprising you saw a divergence.

Comment: A 300 meter error after 10 days is not bad. Not great, but not bad, either. That said, you are comparing semi major axis lengths. Most of the error will typically be along track rather than cross track. I suspect that if you compute the RSS distance discrepancy $\sqrt{(x_G - x_y)^2 + (y_G - y_y)^2 + (z_G - z_y)^2}$, where the $G$ subscript denotes the result from GMAT and the $y$ subscript denotes the result from the @yusuf147 propagation, the discrepancies will be much larger than 300 meters after 10 days.

Comment: First of all, as @DavidHammen said, 300m is not bad. Comparing nummerical propagators was my Master thesis and I did it a few times at my job and im quite impressed. I am not very familiar with phython but in FORTRAN-Code, Doubles are normally sufficient for nummerical propagators, except in some cases for frame transformations, maybe you could have a look on that. Another case you may get problems with double precision is the julian date: if you use that, better use MJD2000. A very common mistake while comparing nummerical propagators are input parameters like gravitational constants.

Comment: Thank you @DavidHammen for your comment. It is very insightful. By considering your suggestion to check the RSS, I get idea to create just single differential equation consisting all perturbation, instead of summing them first then integrating them. By doing so, my expectation is met. By met, it means my numerical propagator now has so much lower discrepancy compared to GMAT (~1m).